# How to search for a particular word using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, if-statement

I searched a lot but I was unable to find a solution to my problem which is I want to search for a particular word from the input (text). Though I only find the first letter.
my code is as:

```
import re

regex = r"([a-zA-Z]+)"
datm = str(input('Enter  a passage to search for a word :'))
if re.search(regex, datm):

    match = re.search(regex, datm)

    print("Full match: %s" % (match.group(0)))

else:

    print("The regex pattern does not match. :(")
```

Thanks for the answer, you don't have to answer if you are going to give minus.

Comment: `\btheparticularword\b` (before that check `str.split` (with help  from `str.strip`) would suffice).

Comment: Are you trying to search for a word in some given text? Right now it looks like you are only trying checking if a user input a word.  IF you want to search some text, where will you get the text from?

Comment: it will be entered from the keyboard such as datm=str(input('enter the text'))

Comment: and some not smart people give minus which banes me from asking and learning though I warn them. I need help not minus.

Comment: Make your question clear and answerable, you will get upvotes. It is not at all clear what your problem is. What is so particular in the word you want to match? Why do you think you need regex at all? Maybe all you need is `datm = str(input('Enter  a passage to search for a word :'))` and then `print(datm)`.

Comment: This `[a-zA-Z]+` would match more than 1 letter if they were there in sequence.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to learn and if I want to search for your name from a text how can I use regex.

Comment: @JanaRuhrländer. May be you need `str.isalpha()` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isalpha.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, maybe you should give a try.

```
import re
xx = str(input('Enter your text '))
richWord1 = re.findall(r"^\w+",xx) #finding the first word
print (richWord1)
```